# Facebook like page on prompt?

Tags: facebook

I have a facebook like button on my site. People can sign up to my site.

I would also like it that when a user logs in for the first time it will prompt them to the like the page? Is this possible?

Is it also possible to get the result of whether they liked it or not?

I basically want to prompt them to like it on their first login, then know the outcome of whether they did or not?

Thanks

**EDIT**

How can I make the fb like box pop up from my code, is there a function I can call in javascript?

How can I get a response on whether they liked the page or not?

Comment: You question is a bit vague, could you explain more clearly? Do you mean pressing like button is mandatory during registration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would also like it that when a user logs in for the first 
>   time it will prompt them to the like the page? Is this possible?

Yes

> How can I make the fb like box pop up from my code, is there a function I can call in javascript?

The like is user initiated and you are not allowed to initiate the popup.  However, you can, once a user logs in, ask the user to like your page prior to showing them any content.  This is called a fan-gate.  Many good examples of fan-gates can be googled.

> Is it also possible to get the result of whether they liked it or not?

Yes

> How can I get a response on whether they liked the page or not?

Subscribe to the "edge.create" event using http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/ .  Then you will know when the user clicks the like button on your page.

Please no followup questions in this thread.  If you have a specific question to ask, please do so in a single question.  Asking many questions in one SO question is not really fair to other users.  Asking followups is also frowned upon.

Comment: Ok cool, I can do the rest from here anyway. Just needed to know where to get the information. Thanks